# How to set gMSA account in physical path credentials property for web application

Tags: iis, path, credentials, gmsa

I have web application running successfully in different environments. Currently I am using the same service account for both application pool and 'Physical Path Credentials' of the web application.

Now I am planning to use gMSA instead of service account. gMSA account has all the required permissions to the network path. I was able to change application pool to use gMSA successfully. However when I try to change 'Physical Path Credentials' of the web application, I am getting 'The specified password is invalid'. Note that when I enter gMSA account, the password field is greyed out. I can't even enter password.

I have searched for solution. But most of the solutions are related to application pool.
[image]

Comment: 1) If some IIS settings become broken, open up `applicationHost.config` and delete them. Then you can start from scratch. 2) Use `appcmd` or PowerShell to configure, which sometimes gives you a more meaningful error message than IIS Manager.

Comment: You can try to I adadd the gMSA account to the local Administrators group to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Microsoft support team. According to them it is not possible to use gMSA for 'Physical Path Credentials'. The reply I received from Microsoft support is as follows:

"we can only configure gmsa account for app pool but we cannot configure it for physical path. It is a by design behavior."

Comment: Thank you for the sharing on the final outcome of this issue, you can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community member in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.